# Processing, keep window on top/ overlay

Tags: window, overlay, processing

I have been looking at this and could not find anything to really help.

I want to make my canvas in Processing to stay over the top of other windows, I have worked out how to do this but when you load up a game the game hides the canvas behind it.

I have found that the following has to be used but I do not know or in what context compared to processing:

DirectDraw or inject a dll and hook directx

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "I have worked out how to do this" - what have you tried? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I can get it to stay on top of other Windows such as file explorer but when you load up a game it is hidden under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Processing 3 (and you should be), then you should no longer use the `frame` variable- the other answer doesn't seem to do anything in Processing 3.

Instead, use the `surface` variable:

```
void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
  surface.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

More info on the changes made in Processing 3 can be found [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0) and [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/3388).

Comment: I will try this but the problem is that I will stay over all windows unless you load up a game, and that is a problem as i wish to use it to overlay a game

Comment: @moose Actually, the problem is that the game **also** has specified that its window should always be on top. If you've got two windows that should always stay on top, then they're the same "priority" and they act like normal windows to each other. You could *try* adding a focus listener to your window (google is your friend), but it might not really be possible to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No need to hook DirectX yourself, just insert this line in your `setup` function:

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

(As an aside, [this thread](https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1181421211.html) on the Processing forum was the first result when googling "processing window stay on top").

Comment: As of Processing 3, you should no longer use the frame variable. The code you posted doesn't seem to have any effect. Check out my answer for more info.

Comment: No worries. Processing 3 included a bunch of changes. I'm still working through them myself. TweakMode is neat though. :p